# date range filter of data table is not working in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I am applying date range filter with the help of package yajra laravel . but it returns me error as "DataTables warning: table id=order_table - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/1"](http://datatables.net/tn/1%22) Please suggest some solution.

This is my view code

```
<main id="main-container">
      <!-- Page Content -->
      <div class="content">
           <h2 class="content-heading">Cashout Details</h2>
           <div class="block block-themed">
               <div class="block-content">
                   <form action="" method="get">
                       <div class="form-group row">
                           <label class="col-12" for="example-select2-multiple">Store Location</label>
                           <div class="col-lg-11">
                               <select class="form-control" name="store" style="width: 100%;" required>
                                   <option value="">Choose Select Store location..</option>                                    
                                   @foreach($stores as $store)
                                   <option @if($store_selected == $store->id) selected @endif value="{{ $store->id }}">{{ $store->channel_id }} | {{ $store->street_name }}</option>
                                   @endforeach
                               </select>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-1">
                               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-alt-success">
                                   Filter
                               </button>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </form>
               </div>
              {{--  <form action="{{ route('cashoutdetails.show') }}" method="get" autocomplete="off"> --}}
               <div class="row m-5 input-daterange">
                       <div class="col-5">
                       <label for="from_date">Start Date</label>
                       <input id="from_date" name="from_date" class="form-control" type="date">
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-5">
                       <label for="to_date">End Date</label>
                       <input id="to_date" name="to_date" class="form-control" type="date">
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-1 cust-1">
                           <button id="filter" name="filter" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Filter</button>
                       </div>
               </div>
         {{--   </form> --}}
           </div> 
           <!-- Dynamic Table Full -->
           <div class="block">
               <div class="block-content block-content-full">
                   @include('errors.error')
                   <div class="float-right">
                   <a href="{{ route('export') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Download">
                       Export to Excel <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                   </button></a>
                   </div>
                   <br/>
                   <div class="table-responsive">
                       <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter js-dataTable-full1" data-page-length='50' id="order_table">
                           <thead>
                               <tr>
                                   <th class="text-center">#</th>
                                   <th class="text-center">Store Name</th>
                                   <th>Recorded Date</th>
                                   <th class="">Closing Report Total</th>
                                   <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%;">Total Deposit</th>
                                   <th>Difference</th>
                                   <th>Prepared By</th>
                                   <th>Deposited By</th>
                                   <th>Deposit Date</th>
                                   <th>Reference Number</th>
                                   <th>Comments</th>
                                   <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%;">Action</th>
                               </tr>
                           </thead>
                       </table>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <!-- END Dynamic Table Full -->
       </div>
   </main>
```

This is my script file

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
           todayBtn:'linked',
           format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
           autoclose:true
           });

           load_data();

           function load_data(from_date = '', to_date = '')
           {
           $('#order_table').DataTable({
           //processing: true,
           //serverSide: true,
           ajax: {
               url:'{{ route("cashoutdetails.filter") }}',
               data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},
               dataSrc: "",
               //response : jQuery.parseJSON(data);
           },
           columns: [
           {
           data:'store_id',
           name:'store_id'
           },
           {
           data:'recorded_date',
           name:'recorded_date'
           },
           {
           data:'closing_report_total',
           name:'closing_report_total'
           },
           {
           data:'total_deposit',
           name:'total_deposit'
           },
           {
           data:'difference',
           name:'difference'
           },
           {
           data:'prepared_by',
           name:'prepared_by'
           },
           {
           data:'deposited_by',
           name:'deposited_by'
           },
           {
           data:'deposit_date',
           name:'deposit_date'
           },
           {
           data:'reference_number',
           name:'reference_number'
           },
           {
           data:'comments',
           name:'comments'
           }
       ]
     /*   error:function(response) {
               var responseTextObject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    /*        } */
       });
       }

           $('#filter').click(function(){
           var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
           var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
           if(from_date != '' &&  to_date != '')
           {
           $('#order_table').DataTable().destroy();
           load_data(from_date, to_date);
           }
           else
           {
           alert('Both Date is required');
           }
           });
       });
   </script>
```

and below is my function of controller

```
 public function filter() 
    {
        //return test;
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            if(!empty($request->from_date))
            {
                $data = DB::table('cash_out_details')
                    ->whereBetween('recorded_date', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date))
                    ->get();
            }
            else
            {
                $data = DB::table('cash_out_details')
                    ->get();
            }
            return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
        }
        return view('cashoutdetails.index');
    }
```

I have followed this article https://www.webslesson.info/2019/07/how-to-implement-date-range-filter-in-laravel-58-datatable.html.

Data is not coming in table where as if i check in console, request is being received and it works

Comment: what happens when you click on `#filter button`?? i think it will reload the page while you want to use ajax

Comment: Data is coming in response but no table entries are being displayed